# What does the following SED pattern exactly do?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, pattern-matching, cgi

I am working on a CGI script and the developer who worked on this before me has used a SED Pattern.

```
COMMAND=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*com_tex=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"`
```

Here `com_tex` is the name of the text box in HTML.

What this line does is it takes a value form the HTML text box and assigns it to a SHELL variable. The SED pattern is apparently (not sure) necessary to extract the value from HTML without the other unnecessary accompanying stuff.

I will also mention the issue what I am asking this. The same pattern is used for a text area where I am entering a command and I need it retrieved exactly as it is. However it's getting jumbled up. Eg. IF I enter the following command in text box:

> /usr/bin/free -m >> /home/admin/memlog.txt

The value that gets stored in the variable is:

> %2Fusr%2Fbin%2Ffree+-m+%3E%3E+%2Fhome%2Fadmin%2Fmemlog.txt

All of us can get that / is being substituted by %2F, a space by + and the > sign by %3E.

But I just can not figure how this is specified in the above pattern! Will someone please tell me how that pattern works or what pattern should I substitute there so that I would get my entered command instead of the output I am getting?

Comment: nothing happend in sed substitution with your entry because there are no pattern matching. So it's in earlier stage of the process. By the way you could avoid the seconf sed by replacing `' |sed"` by a `;` and last double quote by a single.

Answer (score 1):

```
 sed -n
```

`-n` switch means "Dont print"

```
's/
```

s is for substitutions, `/` is a delimiter so the command looks like
`s/Thing to sub/subsitution/optional extra command`

```
^.*com_tex=
```

`^` means the start of the line
`.*` means match 0 or more of any character
So it will match the longest string from the start of the line up to `com_tex=`

```
\(\)
```

This is a capture group, whatever is matched inside these brackets is saved and can be used later

```
[^&]*
```

`[^]` When the hat is used inside square brackets it means do not match any characters inside the brackets
`*` The same as before means 0 or more matches

The capture group combined with this means capture any character except `&`.

```
 .*$
```

The same as the first bit except `$` means the end of the line, so this matches everything until the end

```
/\1/p'
```

After the second `/` is the substitution. `\1` is the capture group from before, so this will substitute everything we matched in the first part(the whole line) with the capture group.
`p` means print, this must be explicitly stated as the `-n` switch was used and will prevent other lines from being printed.

```
|
```

PIPE

```
s/%20/ /g
```

Sub %20 for a space, `g` means global so do it for every match on the line

HTH :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not performed by any of the patterns. My best guess is that this escaping is performed by the shell or whatever fetches the HTML.

I will try to explain the patterns a little at a time

```
sed -n
```

-n specifies that sed should not print out the text to be matched, ie the html, after applying the commands.
The command following is of the form 's/regexp/replacement/flags'

```
^.*com_tex=\([^&]*\).*$
```

^ matches the beginning of the line
.* matches zero to many of any character
com_tex= matches the characters literally
\([^&]*\) '\(' specifies the beginning of a group that can later be backreferenced via its index. '[^&]*' matches zero to many characters which are not '&'. '\)' specifies the end of the group.
.* See above
$ matches the end of the line

```
\1
```

The above replacement is a backreference to the first (and only) group in the regexp i.e. '[^&]*'. So the replacement replaces the entire line with all characters immediately following 'com_tex=' till the first '&'.

The p flag specifies that if a substitution took place, the current line post substitution should be printed.

```
sed "s/%20/ /g"
```

The above is much simpler, it replaces all (not just the first) occurences of '%20' with a space ' '.